# Using require in TypeScript in order to load modules in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a web page on which I would like to use a TypeScript file I created. That web page uses a few modules, most importantly vega-lite, papaparse, and tabulator-tables. I would like to load them into the code via TypeScript, and when I attempt to write into the TS file a line such as the following:

> const Papa = require("papaparse");

I don't get any errors on compiling, but when I load the HTML page I get a `require is not defined` error. I suspect it has something to do with my tsconfig.json, so I'm attaching it. Does anyone know how to solve this? The structure of my project is:

```
node_modules
public
    index.html
    styles.css
    index.js
src
    index.ts
```

And this is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{   
  "compilerOptions":
  {
    "target": "es2021",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./public",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to set `module` to `commonjs` if you're using `require` otherwise use `import`

Comment: `require()` is Node.js syntax, it's not supported in browsers. https://sebhastian.com/javascript-require-is-not-defined/

Comment: To use nodejs in the browser you can use something like https://browserify.org/ . There are other alternatives as well.

Comment: You probably need to use something like [webpack here.](https://webpack.js.org/)

Comment: What's the difference between browserify and webpack?